# Errors with an image replacement

Tags: javascript, image, src, image-replacement

I have tried every possible combination of methods for replacing an image but have found no solution that works.

I uploaded the problematic code here: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2959730/index.html

I would suggest downloading the source and trying your code. The problem lies with the player.playPause() function that should be attached to the #playButt img.

Please help I've been struggling for hours now!

EDIT:

I've corrected everything and as per suggestion I'm using this code now for playPause(), but it **still doesn't work!**. This is the most frustrating thing I have ever dealt with...

```
this.playPause = function(){  
    this.status = !this.status;  
    var status = this.status;
    var playEl = document.getElementById('play');
    $("#play").fadeOut(200, function(){  
        if(status)  
            playEl.src = "img/pauseButton.png";
        else  
            playEl.src = "img/playButton.png";
        $("#play").fadeIn(200); 
    }) 
}
```

Comment: See my update, the entire `div#ipod2` is being cloned, and the duplicate IDs are causing problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>`playPause()` is defined as a property of `var player`, in [playlist.js](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2959730/js/playlist.js).</strike>

Your onclick `onclick="playPause(); return false;"` isn't calling playPause because it can't find the function in the global scope. You need to change your onclick to:

```
onclick="player.playPause(); return false;"
```

**Update:**

The problem is with this callback:

```
$("#play").fadeOut(200, function(){  
    if(this.status)  
        playEl.src = "img/pauseButton.png";
    else  
        playEl.src = "img/playButton.png";
}).fadeIn(200);
```

`this.status` is undefined inside that callback since `this` now refers to the element #play. To fix this problem you need to declare `var status = this.status` before the callback, and test `if(status)` inside the callback.

Two other things:

1. The `.fadeIn(200)` should be placed inside the callback, otherwise it is running before the fadeOut completes (so there's no fade effect at all).
2. You don't need `var playEl = document.getElementById('play');` since you're using jQuery to grab the element. Inside the callback, the `this` keyword refers to the element already.

The complete code should be:

```
var status = this.status = !this.status;
$("#play").fadeOut(200, function(){  
    if(status)  
        this.src = "img/pauseButton.png";
    else  
        this.src = "img/playButton.png";
    $(this).fadeIn(200);
});
```

**Another Update:**

In addition to the above fix, there's a further problem. It looks like there are two elements on the page with `id="play"`. In fact, the whole #ipod2 is duplicated. I checked the source code, but it's not there, only in the live DOM. If you `$("#play").remove();` in the console, you'll see that the image replacement code now works. However, you'll need to find out where ipod2 is being cloned in the JS and fix that.

Comment: it probably has to do with the slider javascript that causes the sliding back and forth. I really appreciate the tip, and I'll definitely look into it.

Comment: Thank you so much. I finally figured it out. I had a never ending function on the slider resulting in a clone of ipod2. I fixed it and it works perfectly. Btw I love you.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't actually attaching to the #playButt image though, from what I can tell. All you're doing is defining the onclick attribute of that image and just calling `playPause`, which isn't defined.

Have you changed the document since you asked your question?

Does it work if you have onclick="player.playPause(); return false;" in your onclick handler for the #playButt image?

Comment: I actually fixed that a while ago... Here I updated the code: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2959730/index.html. It still doesn't work though.

Answer (score 0):

You definitely need to have player.playPause() instead of just playPause().

And you seem to have a problem in the css or height function of slider.js as Firebug reports that a[0] is undefined.